# Size of sample in Random Forest Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

If understand correctly, when Random Forest estimators are calculated usually bootstrapping is applied, which means that a tree(i) is built only using data from sample(i), chosen with replacement. I want to know what is the size of the sample that sklearn [RandomForestRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) uses.

The only thing that I see that is close:

```
bootstrap : boolean, optional (default=True)
    Whether bootstrap samples are used when building trees.
```

But there is no way to specify the size or proportion of the sample size, nor does it tell me about the default sample size.

I feel like there should be way to at least know what the default sample size is, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sample size for bootstrap is always the number of samples.

You are not missing anything, the same question was asked on the [mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/p/scikit-learn/mailman/scikit-learn-general/?viewmonth=201507) for `RandomForestClassifier`:

> The bootstrap sample size is always the same as the input sample size. If you feel up to it, a pull request updating the documentation would probably be quite welcome.

Answer (score 9):

Uhh, I agree with you it's quite strange that we cannot specify the subsample/bootstrap size in `RandomForestRegressor` algo. Maybe a potential workaround is to use `BaggingRegressor` instead. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.BaggingRegressor

`RandomForestRegressor` is just a special case of `BaggingRegressor` (use bootstraps to reduce the variance of a set of low-bias-high-variance estimators). In `RandomForestRegressor`, the base estimator is forced to be `DeceisionTree`, whereas in `BaggingRegressor`, you have the freedom to choose the `base_estimator`.  More importantly, you can set your customized subsample size, for example `max_samples=0.5` will draw random subsamples with size equal to half of the entire training set. Also, you can choose just a subset of features by setting `max_features` and `bootstrap_features`.

Comment: Since  0.22 version, `max_samples` controls `the number of samples to draw from X to train each base estimator.`

Answer (score 4):

In the 0.22 version of scikit-learn, the `max_samples` option has been added, doing what you asked : [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) the documentation of the class.